# mySql Join optimisation query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to optimise my site and would be grateful for some help.

The site is a mobile phone comparison site and the query is to show the offers for a particular phone. The data is on 2 tables, the cmp_deals table has 931000 entries and the cmp_tariffs table has 2600 entries. The common field is the tariff_id.

```
###The deals table###
id  int(11)
hs_id   varchar(30)
tariff_id   varchar(30)
hs_price    decimal(4,2)
months_free     int(2)
months_half     int(2)
cash_back   decimal(4,2)
free_gift   text
retailer_id     varchar(20)

###Deals Indexes###
hs_id   INDEX   430     Edit    Drop    hs_id
months_half     INDEX   33      Edit    Drop    months_half
months_free     INDEX   25      Edit    Drop    months_free
hs_price    INDEX   2223    Edit    Drop    hs_price
cash_back   INDEX<br/>


###The tariff table###
ID  int(11)
tariff_id   varchar(30)
tariff_name     varchar(255)
tariff_desc     text
anytime_mins    int(5)
offpeak_mins    int(5)
texts   int(5)
line_rental     decimal(4,2)
cost_offset     decimal(4,2)
```

No Indexes

The initial query is

```
SELECT * FROM `cmp_deals`
LEFT JOIN `cmp_tariffs` USING (tariff_id)
WHERE hs_id = 'iphone432gbwhite'
```

and then the results can be sorted by various items in the cmp_deals table such as cash_back or free_gift

```
SELECT * FROM `cmp_deals`
LEFT JOIN `cmp_tariffs` USING (tariff_id)
WHERE hs_id = 'iphone432gbwhite'
ORDER BY hs_price DESC
LIMIT 30
```

This is the result when I run an "EXPLAIN" command, but I don't really understand the results.

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra<br/>
1   SIMPLE  cmp_deals   ref     hs_id   hs_id   92  const   179     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort<br/>
1   SIMPLE  cmp_tariffs     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2582
```

I would like to know please if I am doing these queries in the most efficient way as the queries are averaging at 2 seconds plus.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should at least have an index on `tariff_id` on both tables, if you have queries that use this JOIN.

Comment: For this particular query, you may benefit more from an additional index on `(hs_id, tariff_id)`

Comment: And an index on `hs_price` so the ORDER BY/LIMIT is fast.

Comment: @ypercube There already is an index on `cmp_deals.hs_price` and adding an index on `(hs_id, tariff_id)` isn't going to achieve anything

Comment: @Phil: Yes, you're right. Just wasn't sure of what those `Edit`, `Drop`  mean.

Comment: @ypercube I'd say it's been copied from PHPMyAdmin or similar

Comment: @Phil: For a JOIN with `WHERE hs_id = 'iphone432gbwhite'`? I thought it would. But I may be mistaken, it's time to get some sleep.

Comment: @ypercube That's not part of the join and `hs_id` is already indexed. The only way the join will become faster is by having the foreign key (`cmp_deals.tariff_id`) reference an actual primary key

Comment: Yes, I agree on that. If `tariff.tariff_id` was unique or primary key it would be good. And even better, as your suggestion, if the reference was made to a primary key that was shorter, like INT and not a VARCHAR(30).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say I'm a fan of all those double IDs (numeric and human-readable). If you don't actually need the varchar versions, drop them.

Change the foreign key `cmp_deals.tarrif_id` to reference `cmp_tarrifs.ID` (ie, make it an `INT` and if using `InnoDB`, actually create foreign key constraints).

At the very least make `cmp_tariffs.ID` a primary key and optionally `cmp_tariffs.tariff_id` a unique index.

Having zero indexes on the tariffs table means it has to do a table scan to complete the join.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. There is alot of information there;  will try to make the most of it. Thanks @Phil for editing my post to make it more presentable - I was struggling!

Comment: I have created an index on cmp_tariff.tariff_id.

Comment: The database type is MyISAM which means that I cannot create a foreign key. I now understand why it would be better to make reference to a shorter primary key (INT) instead of varchar(30) but unfortunately the tariff_id is the common link between the 2 tables. The ID and id on both the tables are auto increment values - to be honest I don't know why I put them there in the first place. Taking into account the comments I have made about the suggestions, Am I correct in saying that, that query is as fast as its going to get?

Comment: I have just checked the performance with and without the new index on cmp_tariff.tariff_id and it went from 1.7698 to 0.0044. This was for the second query containing ORDER BY. Thanks a lot for your help guys.